# Terraspace using public modules

Tags: terraform, terraspace

recently I found the terraspace framework which is wonderful. I followed the tutorial but now I have a concern in how to work with public modules, for example, I want to create a gcp compute using this module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/vm/google/4.0.0

Comment: Have you learnt how to work with public modules in Terraform in general? If not, start here: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/module-use . If you already understand that, could you clarify your question as it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Terraspace uses Terraform HCL, so you can use the module source keyword to include 3rd party modules, public or private. The @T.H. link provides a good intro using the module source keyword.

Additionally, Terraspace provides a [Terrafile](https://terraspace.cloud/docs/terrafile/) concept that centralizes and automates the management of external modules. You can use any module you want, private or public. Introduction blog post: [Terraspace Terrafile: Using Git and Terraform Registry Modules](https://blog.boltops.com/2020/10/18/terraspace-terrafile-using-git-repos-and-terraform-registry-modules)

It also has several examples showing how to use modules with Terraspace, including [terraspace-google-vm](https://github.com/boltops-tools/terraspace-google-vm)